# python - django - file descriptors not closing

Tags: python, django

I have standalone django program which runs a thread that runs every 5 seconds, reads data from DB using django querysey and publishes it to kafka.

What is happening is that after certain period of time (3-4 days), I get below error

```
File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/conn.py\", line 239, in recv
    readable, _, _ = select([self._sock], [], [], timeout)
ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()",
```

After debugging I found that **file descriptors** on the system were exhausted. But I don't see any resource leak in the program.

**Standalone program**:

```
from g_notifications import process_once as g

thread_event = Event()

def process(obj, source, *args):
    try:
        while True:
            obj(*args)
            thread_event.wait(5)
    except Exception:
        thread_event.set()
        thread_event.clear()

def main():
    django.setup()
    thread_g = Thread(target=process, name='g', args=(g, 'g'))
    thread_g.start()
```

**Thread part**:

```
import socket
from django.db import connection
from notification.kafka_publish import KafkaPublisher
from settings.common import KAFKA_TOPIC

kafka_publisher_g = None

def process_once(publisher_type=KafkaPublisher):
    global kafka_publisher_g
    try:
        socket.gethostbyname('mysql')
    except socket.error:
        return
    
    if kafka_publisher_g is None:
        kafka_publisher_g = publisher_type()
    try:
        notification_objects = list(Notification.objects.all().order_by('id')[:5])
    except Exception as exc:
        log.exception("Unexpected error could not complete database query!")
        return
    finally:
        close_db_connection(connection)
    error_flag = _publish_notification_and_verify(notification_objects)
    if error_flag:
        kafka_publisher_g.close()
        kafka_publisher_g = None

def _publish_notification_and_verify(notification_objects):
    global kafka_publisher_g
    error_flag = False
    for notification_object in notification_objects:
        message = notification_object.notification_data
        try:
            response = kafka_publisher_g.publish(bytes(message))
            if (response is None) or (response.topic != KAFKA_TOPIC):
                error_flag = True
                break
        except Exception as e:
            error_flag = True
        finally:
            close_db_connection(connection)
    return error_flag
```

Sample output of `lsof |  grep <pid>` is:

```
    python    21870       www-data  cwd   unknown                                       /proc/21870/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
    python    21870       www-data  rtd   unknown                                       /proc/21870/root (readlink: Permission denied)
    python    21870       www-data  txt   unknown                                       /proc/21870/exe (readlink: Permission denied)
    python    21870       www-data    0w  unknown                                       /proc/21870/fd/0 (readlink: Permission denied)
.
. *1w, 2w......25w*
.
    python    21870       www-data   26w  unknown                                       /proc/21870/fd/26 (readlink: Permission denied)
    python    21870 21879 www-data  cwd   unknown                                       /proc/21870/task/21879/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
    python    21870 21879 www-data  rtd   unknown                                       /proc/21870/task/21879/root (readlink: Permission denied)
    python    21870 21879 www-data  txt   unknown                                       /proc/21870/task/21879/exe (readlink: Permission denied)
    python    21870 21879 www-data    0w  unknown                                       /proc/21870/task/21879/fd/0 (readlink: Permission denied)
.
.
.
    python    21870 21879 www-data   26w  unknown                                       /proc/21870/task/21879/fd/26 (readlink: Permission denied)
```

This grows by 5-6 FDs after some random time ranging from 10 minutes to 30 minutes.

I am not sure what I am missing here. I think I am closing all connections properly. Is this some issue with django/python or I am missing anything?

I am using kafka-python=1.0.2 and django version 1.8.

Comment: Your `except Exception as exc: ... return` does not close the handler. It does not look like a good idea to use a `global`, and you might want to look if you can use a context manager to automatically close in case of an exception.

Comment: Connection is being closed in finally. And I am not getting any exceptions in logs. So safe to say exception is not being hit.

Comment: but the `kafka_publisher_g.close()` is only called *after* the `finally` block, so if you use `return`, the logic will never pass *after* the `finally` block.

Comment: Yeah. that is because I want to initialize kafka_publisher_g once and use it till there is some exception in publishing kafka. I did try to close it for every run of the thread. Turns out FDs were increasing 200 times every minute.